# MIMIC-III linking d_icd table with diagnosis_icd

Tags: mimic-iii

I wanted to map the `DIAGNOSES_ICD` codes and `PROCEDURES_ICD` codes to `D_DIAGNOSES_ICD` and `D_PROCEDURES_ICD` code but I get a `Relationship doesn't exist` error. Is there a way around it?

Comment: Can you add the code you tried?